# Using getText() with LocalDate Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, localdate

I'm making a GUI in java for a todo list and i want to write a todo type object in a file. A todo object has name, description and a date that determinds this to be done. With GUI a user can add as many todo objects he wants with them be written to a file. I'm having trouble getting the date from user from a JTextField using getText() and parsing it in a LocalDate type object in order to be written in the file.

Code I'm running now:

//registration method

```
public void RegularObligationRegister(RegularObligations R) throws IOException {
   try {

        objOutObligations.writeObject(R);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Save Success");

        System.out.println(R);

        objOutObligations.flush();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {   
        System.out.println("Error with specified file . . .");
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

//actionperformed method

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
.
.
.
if (ae.getSource().equals(REntryObligationSave)) {

RegularObligations R = new RegularObligations(RegularEntry_TextObligationName.getText(), 
RegularEntry_TextObligationDescription.getText(), 
LocalDate.parse(RegularEntry_TextObligationDeadline.getText()));

        try {
            this.RegularObligationRegister(R);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        RegularEntry_TextObligationName.setText(null);
        RegularEntry_TextObligationDescription.setText(null);
        RegularEntry_TextObligationDeadline.setText(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that your text must be valid LocalDate.parse() method to parse. You need to specify your text format for the LocalDate. For ex: (dd MMM uuuu). Then you should pass your text and formatter to the LocalDate.parse() method as parameter.  The example below will help you to parse a String similar to : "31 Dec 2018" as a LocalDate

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu");

LocalDate.parse(RegularEntry_TextObligationDeadline.getText(),formatter));
```

You can check DateTimeFormatter to customize your datetype as a text [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)